# Referencing own work in answer

Tags: discussion, promotion

In [the question Universal Etymology of Words](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1506/universal-etymology-of-words/) A user wrote [an extensive answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/1801/92) based mostly in his own book. Our FAQ does allow self-reference, and indeed there have been many great answers which are posted by experts and cite their own work. But there are certain conditions:

> Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and
>   tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant
>   answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or
>   website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your
>   answers. If a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your
>   product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons.

This one seems particularly problematic because:

- It is not written in neutral tone (e.g. third person)
- A significant part of the answer contains self-promotion instead of actually answering the question.
- The writer's credentials as well as the book's reliability is not clear (it doesn't seem to be published or reviewed by a reputable entity).
- The part that acknowledge that the book is written by the answerer himself was removed [not the answerer's fault]

What can we do to improve the guideline/rules for self-reference in this SE?

Answer (score 1):

I think the Stack Exchange full disclosure rule is enough.

If crackpots want to expose themselves among the experts here then I hope the experts will find some credible refutations.

And who knows once in a blue moon a harebrained theory might pan out.

I say let the arguments stand on their merits, as long as they meet all the requirements of Stack Exchange. Disclose your own work, stay on topic, answers must address the actual question, be civil, try not to use 2-page paragraphs with no breaks and sporadic all-caps sentences (-;

In fact I would go so far as to encourage anybody here who has a favourite hated theory to ask a question about it here. Why shouldn't we be a go-to source for solid credible information on why some shaky theories are shaky.

Just be civil and avoid flamewars and I know it sounds like trolling, but hopefully we're good enough to weed out real troll questions from deunking questions.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: On second thought I undeleted it. I don't want it to sound like a "conflict of interest" considering the other answer is mine. I'll let another moderator handle it.

---

<s>I deleted it, so only Moderators or 10K users<sup>1</sup> can see it. I deleted it because it received flags about its content being a little too "aggressive" if  we can use this term. In any case, I deleted it until we manage to solve this issue.</s>

I think you forgot the main problem, though. The answer *doesn't answer* the question. Sorry for the play on words, but that's what happens. I don't think it answers the question honestly. If it has any relevance, it's lost in the answer and I can't see it.

---

<sup>1: By 10K I mean users with moderation tools, so you don't need to have 10,000 reputation, it's just the name. On this site, at the moment, you need to have 2,000 rep to see deleted answers or questions.</sup>